# Remap a windows keyboard shortcut to output a PowerShell/cmd command result?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, powershell, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-11

I'm looking for a way to bind a custom shortcut (say Ctrl+G) in such a way, that upon pressing it I'd get a small powershell/cmd command executed and the contents of which would be then either pushed to the clipboard or just outputted directly as a paste. More concretely, I'd like to speed up my workflow by having ability to generate guid's on demand in the quickest way possible, so I'd like remap Ctrl+G to execute
[guid]::NewGuid() and then immediately output it in whichever active area is selected.

I've played around with MS PowerToys, it looks possible to create a mapping to one of the VK (Virtual-Key) codes, but it's a little unclear to me how to bind an output of executable/script to it (should be possible through registry editing?).

Would prefer if the solution doesn't involve any third party programs like AHK, although I'm willing to go that route if there's nothing else.

Thanks!

System:
Windows 11 PRO, 22000.556

Answer (score 2):

You may use the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following example script will map
<kbd>F12</kbd>
to run a PowerShell command that will copy a new GUID to the clipboard:

```
F12::powershell "[guid]::NewGuid() | Set-Clipboard"
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation
(for changing changing F12 to another key-combination):

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)